# How can i get then "=" Php parse

Tags: php, parsing, parse-url

I need help on php.
I get full link with this code

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

My link output is: http://localhost/Mid/photo-gallery/photos.php?ref=3%20%20ID=3
How can i get "3" ? I need last number. This number can be 3 digits. So maybe can be 444.

Comment: Why not `$_GET['ref']` or `$_GET['ID']`?

Comment: $_GET['ID'] is null. But problem is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using the following code.It will work for you.

```
  $url = " http://localhost/Mid/photo-gallery/photos.php?ref=3%20%20ID=3 ";
  $urls = explode("ID=",$url);  
  echo $urls[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
$idVal = substr(strrchr($url, "="), 1);
```

It will return everything after the last equal. You have to be sure that ID will **always** be your last get parameter in your URL though.